# Why would you use Ramda's lenses over evolve/path?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lenses

Is there some functionality that lenses offer that you cannot get with path/assocPath/evolve/adjust?

Comment: Simply put, lenses offer a higher-level abstraction. The lens itself is a data structure and it's composable with other lenses. And programs written using lens offer equational reasoning. By contrast, `path`, `assocPath`, etc are utility functions that operate on basic data. You can achieve the same thing, but it will take much more code and it will be a lot messier.